# what is basic difference between J2ME MIDlets and blackberry RIMlets

Tags: blackberry, java-me, midp, midlet

I just started with Blackberry application development. What are differences between  J2ME MIDlets and Blackberry RIMlets? Which is better for GUI Applications for Blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main difference is that : RIMLet only can work on BlackBerry devices while MIDlets  can work on any devices that have the Java Virtual Machine installed on it.

See [this](http://www.programmingodyssey.com/2011/03/midlets-vs-blackberry-applications.html) for the information

Comment: Strictly speaking, source code used to compile RIMlets can be reused out of the box to compile MIDlets IF AND ONLY IF the source code uses APIs both available on MIDlets and RIMLets. For instance: an application developed using only JSR-118 API will work on both RIMlet and MIDlets enabled devices.

Now, a RIMlet executable will not work on MIDlet enabled devices since RIM uses COD files instead of JAR files. The compilation/packaging/signing steps are differents on both platforms and use very different tools.

Hope this helps